# How to move the Focus of the keyboard in android?

Tags: android

I made a login page... when even i enter the login page then the keyboard always popup to fill in the entry.. i need to control this popup in my mobile.
I tried setFocusable(false).. still no use... Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this line after `super` in `onCreate()`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```